# Can Byakuya overcome Aizen's Kyoka Suigetsu as easy as he overcomed Koga since both of them are based on illusion?

Tags: bleach

[image]

> Byakuya breaks free and readies himself against Kōga, who is
> determined to use his illusions on Senbonzakura as well. Before he can
> attempt to do so, Byakuya activates his Bankai, Senbonzakura
> Kageyoshi, and uses Senkei, which Byakuya notes will allow him to
> overcome Kōga's illusions because his blades will always find Kōga.
> The two clash evenly several times until Kōga uses his Spiritual
> Threads to bind Byakuya once more. However, Senbonzakura has several
> Senkei blades rain down and cut the threads, to Kōga's surprise.
> Byakuya attacks him, but Kōga moves out of the way and wonders how
> Byakuya can be so powerful. Though Byakuya and Senbonzakura explain
> how their working in unison allows them to unleash their full power,
> Kōga refuses to listen and proclaims his greatness was never
> acknowledged.
>
> [Bleach anime; Episode 252]

If Byakuya's Senkei will always find illusion based shinigami, does that mean he can overcome Aizen's Kyoka Suigetsu illusion just as easily with his Bankai? The war would be so much simpler with Byakuya, wouldn't it? Or there is something different with how Aizen's Kyoka Suigetsu work?

Answer (score -1):

> If Byakuya's Senkei will always find illusion based shinigami, does that mean he can overcome Aizen's Kyoka Suigetsu illusion just as easily with his Bankai?

Not even close. Here's why:

- Both illusions are water based however while Byakuya's Senkei uses his reiatsu, Aizen's Kyoka Suigetsu is just it's power.
- We also have to note that Kyoka Suigetsu manipulates 5 senses which is something Senkei  can't do.
- You can't see Aizen activating his Kyoka Suigetsu in a verbal way. That is because you as the viewer and characters in the show can't see. The moment he activates it you are done. You are in Aizen's world now. Sad thing is you don't even know it.